# how to find sum of number between two zeroes and group by specific column in R

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in R

```
ClientID <- c("c100","c100","c100","c100","c100","c100","c101","c101","c101",
          "c101","c102","c102","c102","c102","c102","c102","c103","c103",
          "c103","c103")

Month <- c("01","02","03","04","05","06","01","02","03","04",
      "01","02","03","04","05","06","01","02","03","04")

Returns <- c(23,0,0,12,0,11,0,0,345,234,123,0,0,23,0,22,34,0,44,21)

      ClientID Month Brokerage
 1      c100    01        23
 2      c100    02         0
 3      c100    03         0
 4      c100    04        12
 5      c100    05         0
 6      c100    06        11
 7      c101    01         0
 8      c101    02         0
 9      c101    03       345
 10     c101    04       234
 11     c102    01       123
 12     c102    02         0
 13     c102    03         0
 14     c102    04        23
 15     c102    05         0
 16     c102    06        22
 17     c103    01        34
 18     c103    02         0
 19     c103    03        44
 20     c103    04        21

 Final_data$Flag <- ifelse(Final_data$Brokerage > 0 ,0,1)
```

After adding flag dataframe looks like this

```
     ClientID Month Brokerage Flag
1:     c100    01        23    0
2:     c100    02         0    1
3:     c100    03         0    1
4:     c100    04        12    0
5:     c100    05         0    1
6:     c100    06        11    0
7:     c101    01         0    1
8:     c101    02         0    1
9:     c101    03       345    0
10:     c101    04       234    0
11:     c102    01       123    0
12:     c102    02         0    1
13:     c102    03         0    1
14:     c102    04        23    0
15:     c102    05         0    1
16:     c102    06        22    0
17:     c103    01        34    0
18:     c103    02         0    1
19:     c103    03        44    0
20:     c103    04        21    0
```

I have flaged customers who have returns more than 0 as 0 and if they have not given any returns for month as 1. My aim is to find sum of 1's between zeroes at customer level. Purpose is to check if the customer is dormant or not.

Expected output is

```
c100 2,1 
c101 Null
c102 2,1
c103 1
```

Logic is to sum 1's between zeroes. 
I can get the sum of 1's between two zeroes for entire column with following code.

```
sum.between.zeroes <- function(x) {
 library(stringr)
 x.str <- paste(x, collapse = "")
 nchar(str_extract_all(x.str, "01+0")[[1]]) - 2L
}

sum.between.zeroes(Final_data$Flag)

2 2 2 1
```

Above output is correct,but I want it to be aggregated at customer level. 
I was trying with dplyr,but does not seems to work.

```
test <- Final_data %>% 
 group_by(ClientID) %>% 
 summarise(Flags = sum.between.zeroes(Flag))
```

Please help.

Comment: Do you need `library(data.table);setDT(Final_data)[, .(sum.between.zeros=sum(Brokerage)), .(ClientID, grp = rleid(Brokerage==0))]`

Comment: I do not need sum of brokerage. I need sum of Flags between two zeroes.

Comment: Can you update with the expected output (for reference)?

Comment: Anyway, with `data.table` `setDT(Final_data)[, .(Flags=sum.between.zeroes(Flag)) , ClientID]` works

Comment: I have edited question with expected output.

Comment: Currently it returns 2 for c100 but c100 has 011010 so it should return 2 and 1. Do I have to make changes in function?

Comment: In that case, your function may need changes

Comment: How do I change it?

Comment: @akrun can you please help?

Comment: Are you sure that the expected output is right?

Comment: @akrun Yes,expected output is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `base R` version.  We `split` the 'Brokerage' by 'ClientID', ge the `range` of position in 'Brokerage' that are not 0, subset the elements in the `list`, use `rle` to get the `length` of each set of 0's, and `stack` the `list` to create a `data.frame`

```
with(Final_data, stack(lapply(split(Brokerage, ClientID), function(x) {
        i1 <- range(which(x!=0))
      toString(with(rle(x[i1[1]:i1[2]]==0), lengths[values])) })))[2:1]
#   ind values
#1 c100   2, 1
#2 c101       
#3 c102   2, 1
#4 c103      1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for your answers. Appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

A simple approach using `diff()` to check `which` is `0`

```
> diff(which(c(0,1,1,1,0,1)==0))-1
#[1] 3
> diff(which(c(0,1,0,1,1,0,1)==0))-1
#[1] 1 2
> diff(which(c(0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0)==0))-1
#[1] 1 2 1
```

Answer :

```
library(dplyr)
Final_data %>% group_by(ClientID) %>%
               summarise(x = paste(diff(which(Flag==0))-1,collapse = ",")) 

#  ClientID     x
#    <fctr> <chr>
#1     c100   2,1
#2     c101     0
#3     c102   2,1
#4     c103   1,0
```

if you want to avoid even the 0's :

```
func <- function(x){
  y = diff(which(x==0))-1
  return(paste(y[y!=0],collapse = ","))
}

Final_data %>% group_by(ClientID) %>%
  summarise(x = func(Flag))
#  ClientID     x
#    <fctr> <chr>
#1     c100   2,1
#2     c101      
#3     c102   2,1
#4     c103     1
```

Comment: did it answer your question? on your real data?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can accomplish this with `aggregate` in base R:

```
myCalc <- aggregate(Returns ~ ClientID, data=df,
                    function(x) {
                                 temp <- rle(x)
                                 toString(paste0(temp$length[temp$value=="0"]))
                     })

myCalc
  ClientID Returns
1     c100    2, 1
2     c101       2
3     c102    2, 1
4     c103       1
```

`rle` calculates the lengths of 0-runs, these are pasted together with `paste0` and coerced into a string with `toString`. The grouping is performed with `aggregate`.

Comment: c101 has 1100,so it should not return anything.As per your logic its returning 2. I want to sum values of flag column between zeroes grouped by clientID

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your function with `gregexpr()`, the `match.length` after the matches is what you are looking for:

```
library(dplyr)

sum.between.zeroes <- function(x) {
  x.str <- paste(x, collapse = "")
  regmatch <- gregexpr("(?<=0)1+(?=0)", x.str, perl = TRUE)

  # if nothing matches return NA else the match.length attribute
  if(length(regmatch[[1]]) == 1 && regmatch[[1]] == -1) NA
  else list(attr(regmatch[[1]], "match.length"))
}

df %>% group_by(ClientID) %>% 
       summarise(Flags = sum.between.zeroes(Flag)) %>% 
       as.data.frame()

#  ClientID Flags
#1     c100  2, 1
#2     c101  NULL
#3     c102  2, 1
#4     c103     1
```